# How to decode this DBC definition of CANbus?

Tags: can-bus

I wrote a `.DBC` file decoder which works very well.

But as I add a new hardware DBC, for the following message, my code does not decode these signals correctly. Here is the DBC portion:

```
BO_ 2566852816 ERROR_INFO: 8 Vector__XXX
 SG_ Slot4_Error_Reserved : 62|7@0+ (1,0) [0|127] "" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Slot3_Error_Reserved : 46|7@0+ (1,0) [0|127] "" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Slot2_Error_Reserved : 30|7@0+ (1,0) [0|127] "" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Slot1_Error_Reserved : 14|7@0+ (1,0) [0|127] "" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Slot4_Error_State : 49|3@0+ (1,0) [0|7] "#" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Slot3_Error_State : 33|3@0+ (1,0) [0|7] "#" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Slot2_Error_State : 17|3@0+ (1,0) [0|7] "#" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Slot4_Error_Id : 55|6@0+ (1,0) [0|63] "#" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Slot3_Error_Id : 39|6@0+ (1,0) [0|63] "#" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Slot2_Error_Id : 23|6@0+ (1,0) [0|63] "#" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Slot1_Error_State : 1|3@0+ (1,0) [0|7] "#" Vector__XXX
 SG_ Slot1_Error_Id : 7|6@0+ (1,0) [0|63] "#" Vector__XXX
```

Here is the bytes for the `ERROR_INFO` frame I receive:

`04 00 08 00 0D 00 10 00`

BMS master decodes it like so, which looks fine to me:

| Signal | Decoded value |
| --- | --- |
| Slot2_Error_Reserved | 0 |
| Slot3_Error_Id | 3 |
| Slot4_Error_State | 0 |
| Slot3_Error_Reserved | 0 |
| Slot2_Error_State | 0 |
| Slot4_Error_Id | 4 |
| Slot4_Error_Reserved | 0 |
| Slot2_Error_Id | 2 |
| Slot1_Error_Reserved | 0 |
| Slot3_Error_State | 2 |
| Slot1_Error_Id | 1 |
| Slot1_Error_State | 0 |

If we focus on the definition of `Slot1_Error_State` — aka `1|3@0+`— this means:

- `start bit` is 1, aka the second;
- `length` is 3 bits;
- and 0 means big endian (1 would have meant little endian);
- the`+` means unsigned.

As per my understanding of the DBC format, starting at bit 1 for 3 bits is nonsense. But this proves that I am wrong.

I tried to decode the values, and I made it, as follows:

[image]

As you can see on my drawing, I got the ID and states identical to what bmsMaster found.

But, I pull my hair to understand how this relies to the definition the DBC contains.

Anyone can explain, step by step, how to apply the two rules I talked about at the beginning of the question, pls?

Comment: CAN frames are big endian. As for the protocol payload then generally big endian is more common than little endian (except for CANopen which always uses little endian). But most microcontrollers nowadays (all the ARMs) are little endian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion comes from the fact that your signals are defined as big-endian.
I often get confused myself when big and little endian are mixed.

If you try to visualize `Slot1_Error_State`, it should actually start at Byte0 least significant bits (1, then 0) and end at Byte1 most significant bit:

[image]